# vaadin-grid element: one input filter for all columns

Tags: polymer, filtering, multiple-columns, vaadin-grid

I'm trying to add a external paper-input out fo the vaadin-grid element in order to filter by any column.

For the moment I did not found a good approach for it, any idea for it?

Each answer will be really appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two way binding

```
<paper-input type="text" value="{{filterVal}}"></paper-input>
 <vaadin-grid-sorter path="name">Name</vaadin-grid-sorter>
                <vaadin-grid-filter path="name" value="[[filterVal]]">
                </vaadin-grid-filter>
```

Comment: This will only filter column with name `name`.

Comment: with same approach you can filter any column   
`<vaadin-grid-sorter path="desc">Description</vaadin-grid-sorter>
                <vaadin-grid-filter path="desc" value="[[filterVal]]">
                </vaadin-grid-filter>`
or multiple columns as well

Comment: He wants to filter all the columns using one input.

Comment: you can add multiple colums
`<paper-input type="text" value="{{filterVal}}"></paper-input>
 <vaadin-grid id="grid">
            <vaadin-grid-column>
     <vaadin-grid-sorter path="name">Name</vaadin-grid-sorter>
                    <vaadin-grid-filter path="name" value="[[filterVal]]">
                    </vaadin-grid-filter>
    </vaadin-grid-column>
    <vaadin-grid-column>
    <vaadin-grid-sorter path="desc">Description</vaadin-grid-sorter>
             <vaadin-grid-filter path="desc" value="[[filterVal]]">
            </vaadin-grid-filter>
    </vaadin-grid-column>`

Comment: This will not work as intended. When you filter two columns using the same input, the filtered text must appear in _both_ columns (logical AND), but the OP probably wants to filter _either_ column (logical OR). I am afraid this cannot be done this way and the filtering must probably be done on the array itself.